# Immutability and custom deserialization in Scala

Tags: scala, deserialization, immutability

Functional programmers taught us the immutability über alles and, thus to declare all fields as **val**s other than **var**s. Personally, I also like to enforce the field constancy with the compiler. But, how do you initialize those fields during custom deserialization?

I have checked, system deserialization is fine to update the constants

```
case class S(value: String) extends Serializable {

    private def writeObject(out: ObjectOutputStream)  = out.defaultWriteObject()

    private def readObject(in: ObjectInputStream) {
        println("restoring " + this) // restoring S(null)
        in.defaultReadObject()
        println("restored to " + this) // restored S(string 1)
    }


}
```

whereas I mannually cannot do the same

```
case class I(value: Int) extends Serializable {

    private def readObject(in: ObjectInputStream) {
        value = in.readInt() // compilation error "reassignment to val"
    }

}
```

Comment: If you need customize default java serialization, you should probably make  serializable builder. Builder concept is common between OOP and FP and could serve as bridge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One word: reflection. In particular, Java reflection. Java reflection doesn't know anything about Scala's semantics, so it will happily let you do things that are forbidden in Scala. In fact, Java's reflection system is *unsafe*, it will even let you do things that are forbidden in Java!

If you look at [the source code for `Serializable`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/Serializable.scala#L14), you will see that it is actually empty. And simply relies on Java's serialization.

(In fact, in some cases, you don't even need reflection to break Scala's semantics. Java will happily let you extend a `sealed` trait or class, because Java doesn't know about `sealed`.)

Comment: According to my experience, java reflection is unaware about Java identifiers. You must enter field/mehtod names as strings, which are not checked by compiler and go out of sync with code base as a feather in the wind. Probably you meant another reflection but I cannot see because link is broken.

Comment: Here is a running demo with reflection http://scastie.org/13233 -- 6 lines of code + corresponding runtime overhead. It seems that requalifying valval => var is cheaper :)

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov that link is broken.  What exactly should the implementation of readObject look like?